# Outlook adds unwanted gaps to tables in email

Tags: css, responsive-design, outlook, html-table, html-email

I have developed a responsive email design but Outlook keeps adding a gap after one of my tables. I have tried everything. I have added border-collapse:collapse; I have divided tables; added block styling to my images - nothing is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The html can be found [here.](http://media.monavie.com/HTML/3262014-recognition-US-2.html) 
Image example of issue [here.](http://media.monavie.com/HTML/responsive.png)

Comment: i think you need valign="top" on the <td> tag containing both the left content and right content nested tables

Comment: Did all of that - still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

instead of giving the `float` property to tables. it would be better to make 2 columns and then placed each table in each column.

just for your information `Outlook.com` drops margin and float support entirely

Comment: I agree - if this email wasn't designed to be responsive. I need the columns in separate tables so that the right column drops down when the content is being viewed on smart phone or tablet. I may have to forgo the second column.

Comment: You can make responsive mail still. I'll send you my example i used table but its responsive .

Answer (score 0):

I would go the direction of [antwort](http://internations.github.io/antwort/) and use table columns that are forced to full-width `display: block;` with media queries (instead of floating tables next to eachother).

See your modified HTML [**`here`**](http://codepen.io/ryanw/pen/JABIf/). I haven't tested it, though. It may need more work, email clients are notoriously frustrating.